# Make better machine learning prediction thanks to negative feedback

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn

I'm currently using sklearn library in python to use supervised machine learning.
I have a list of records like this:

```
[x1, x2, x3] -> [y1]
```

And i'm using the Bag Of Words technique. It all works.
Sometimes it could happen that the user says the prediction is not right.

Something like a negative record:

```
[x1, x2, x3] != [y1]
```

I would like that if this happens the next time (or after many negative feedbacks) the same prediction won't appear.

Comment: You either have to retrain your model (e.g. every day) or you have to implement some logic to your app to handle this.

Comment: I'm already planning to retrain at periodic intervals my model, Do I just need to add the different record and keep the old one?

Comment: If you think that the action of the users is well-intented, you should remove the old one and add the different record. However, this could mean that the users can manipulate the system. Another option is to use the 'sample_weight' argument available in many scikit models to give less weight (e.g. 1/10) to records provided by user feedback. This way, if many users make the same correction, the model will take that into account while if only one user does this, the model would remain unaffected.

Comment: Thank you, I think sample_weight will do this for me.